# Compare integral numbers in a makefile?

Tags: shell, makefile, gnu-make

I have the following in my GNU makefile:

```
# Undefined Behavior Sanitizer (Clang 3.2 and GCC 4.8 and above)
UBSAN = 0
ifeq ($(findstring ubsan,$(MAKECMDGOALS)),ubsan)
UBSAN = 1
CXXFLAGS += -fsanitize=undefined
endif # UBsan

# Address Sanitizer (Clang 3.2 and GCC 4.8 and above)
ASAN = 0
ifeq ($(findstring asan,$(MAKECMDGOALS)),asan)
ASAN = 1
CXXFLAGS += -fsanitize=address
endif # Asan

# Effectively a NOR
ifneq ($(shell echo $$($(ASAN) * $(UBSAN))),0)
$(error Asan and UBsan are mutually exclusive. Specify only one of them)
endif
```

The idea is to detect `make ubsan asan` (or user overrides to `CFLAGS` and `CXXFLAGS`), and error out if both are specified.

Unfortunately, its firing with no command targets:

```
$ make
/bin/sh: 1: 0: not found
GNUmakefile:64: *** Asan and UBsan are mutually exclusive. Specify only one of them.  Stop.
```

I also tried quoting the `"0"` with the same result: `ifneq ($(shell echo $$($(ASAN) * $(UBSAN))),"0")`.

How do I compare two integral values in a makefile?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is a simple typo.

You left out one `(`/`)` in the arithmetic expansion in the `$(shell)` command.

Your shell command is `echo $(0 * 0)` which the shell sees as a command substitution not arithmetic expansion and then tries to run `0 <expansion of all files in the current directory> 0`. Which is why you get the `/bin/sh: 1: 0: not found` error message.

Add the missing `(`/`)` and your problem goes away.

```
ifneq ($(shell echo $$(($(ASAN) * $(UBSAN)))),0)
```

That being said I wouldn't bother using the shell for this at all (it is expensive).

All you are trying to test, in this case, is that `$(ASAN)` and `$(UBSAN)` are not **both** `1`. So just assert that.

```
ifeq ($(ASAN)$(UBSAN),11)
$(error Asan and UBsan are mutually exclusive. Specify only one of them)
endif
```

If you want to be safer about manual assignment of some other value (e.g. `make ASAN=11` or something) then you could do something more like:

```
ifeq ($(filter-out 1,$(ASAN))$(filter-out 1,$(UBSAN)),)
$(error Asan and UBsan are mutually exclusive. Specify only one of them)
endif
```

Comment: *"`ifeq ($(ASAN)$(UBSAN),11)`* - Oh, that's clever, thanks. I despise Make's lack of logical operators, and I'll do anything to avoid nesting `if` statements.